# .net cf - launch explorer programmatically

Tags: .net, compact-framework, shellexecute

I am trying to launch explorer programmatically from my .Net CF Window application. But its throwing win32 exception. I have used same kind of code in desktop .Net version, and it always worked.
(I am using Windows CE 5 and .Net CF 3.5 )

Following code throws Win32 Exception,

```
Process.Start("\\", null);
```

Unfortunately, I am using the code like this :-(

```
try
{ Process.Start("\\", null); }
catch { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should give it a program name to start?  "\" is not an application.  Something like this is probably more likely to yield success:

```
Process.Start("\\windows\\explorer.exe", null);
```

Comment: In Desktop .Net  'Process.Start("C:/dir")' used to work, so i tried to do it in same way. Following code worked in Win CE5 , 'Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\\")'

Answer (score 0):

In order to kick off a web browser navigation to a URL, I have always directly set the argument of the Start method to the url itself. Please try the following to see if it helps in .NET CF"

Process.Start("http://www.yahoo.com", null);

i.e.

Process.Start([url_variable], null);

Comment: This question is about the File Explorer, not Internet Explorer.