# Cannot launch File Explorer in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've got a .NET compact framework application that I'm porting from Windows CE to Windows Mobile 6.1.  The application offers the ability to launch the File Explorer opened to a particular folder as a time-saver for the user when they need to interact with the file system.

The code to do this is trivial (note that `profileLocation` has the path to the target folder to view):

```
try
{
   string fileExplorer = "\\windows\\fexplore.exe";
   Process.Start(fileExplorer, "/root," + profileLocation);
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Could not open " + profileLocation);
}
```

FYI, this is similar to the code found here on SO ([.net cf - launch explorer programmaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094484/net-cf-launch-explorer-programmaticly)).

This works wonderfully on the Windows CE device (and a version of this code works on the full desktop version of the app too), but on the Windows Mobile version the code does nothing.  It does not throw the exception (so I know the process is started at least), but neither does it seem to start the File Explorer.

My first thought was that it was started, but is just behind my application in the stack.  But I have confirmed via `CE Remote Spy` and `CE Remote Process Viewer` that the process is not present at all.

Has anyone achieved this before on a Windows Mobile device?

---

EDIT:

Based upon the suggestion below, I have confirmed that the following code does work:

```
Process.Start(fileExplorer, null);
```

Now I just need to determine what command line options can be used to get File Explorer to launch with the desired file location selected.  Anyone know what command-line options are available for FEXPLORE on WinMo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly fexplore.exe is blacklisted. Can you start fexplore manually?

Try without using a argument and just launch fexplore.exe.

Try your code with another exe.

Generally the code should work fine on windows mobile 6.1.

Comment: It does start without any command-line options.  Half-way there!  Thanks.

Comment: Solved, thanks!  Omitting the `/root,` portion in the command-line args worked for this device.  Yet another thing I need to add to my device abstraction to deal with the differences.

Comment: Should that not be "\\root" to let fexplore open a specific folder?

Comment: For this device,  just passing the folder location as the arg,  without the root switch, worked.  With the root switch it does not launch.